# Optimal setup for mysql db for data of variable depth

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Given a data set that is recursive in structure but may vary in depth from data point to data point, what is the best way to setup a mysql database.

I know this may be a confusing so here is an example of what I mean. Lets say you wanted to store male lineage for a group of people. Not all people can trace this to the same point. Person1 may be able to trace it to his grandfather, person2 to his great-grandfather, and person3 to his great-great-grandfather. I don't think it would make sense to have a table for each possible case of great^nth degree.

My solution is to have a single "father" table which stores the id of its parent or null once the end of the tree is reached. However, the only way I have found to build the full tree is to have a single query for each parent request until a null parent is found.

Does anyone have any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be not to trace grand fathers within the database.
A typical row should be like:

> person_id, person_name, biological_father_person_id,
>   biological_mother_person_id, etc...

Then you can calculate the grand fathers on the application side.

Once your code hits real use, you can start tracking slow queries and start optimizing as necessary. At some point, you might need to denormalize a little. Maybe you will need to keep one or two columns readily pre-processed.

But don't setup a denormalized structure before you have an idea on where the load will be.